# Cannot create xmlns for Xamarin.Forms project namespace

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm encountering the following compilation error when I try to create a new XAML namespace for my current project

```
Error: Failed to resolve assembly: 'TodoQ.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

I have been using custom controls from both my own and an external project and the compiler has never complained about either. Here is the XAML (the ellipses is some other standard namespaces I decided to omit):

```
<ContentPage xmlns:util="clr-namespace:TodoQ.Utilities" 
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:TodoQ.Controls" 
             xmlns:swipecards="clr-namespace:SwipeCards.Controls;assembly=SwipeCards.Controls"
             ... x:Class="TodoQ.Views.ItemsPage" Title="{Binding Title}" x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">
```

As you can see, I have two namespaces which refer to my current Xamarin.Forms project. The `custom` namespace works, but if I try to use `util` I get the above error. On the other hand, the `swipecards` namespace works perfectly.

I have tried specifying the assembly, like so `xmlns:util="clr-namespace:TodoQ.Utilities;assembly=TodoQ"`, but it doesn't appear to make a difference.

My only use of `util` thus far has been trying to add a converter:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <util:IsZero x:Key="IsZero" />
</Grid.Resources>
```

Does anybody know what it is I am doing wrong? I'm practically tearing my hair out here. Things are so much simpler with the WPF version of XAML, it all just seems to work there.

EDIT: Here is the Utilities file as requested:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TodoQ.Utilities
{
    public class IsZero : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value,
                             Type targetType,
                             object parameter,
                             CultureInfo language)
        {
            return ((int)value) == 0;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value,
                             Type targetType,
                             object parameter,
                                  CultureInfo language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Paste your namespace and class name of your Utilities file ie the top part of the file, or the whole file if its small

Comment: @TheGeneral See my edit, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should change your assembly name to `TodoQ.exe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly think its something else, It might be the way your trying to use it,  your code is Correct :

**ItemsPage**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:util="clr-namespace:TodoQ.Converters;assembly=TodoQ"  
    x:Class="TodoQ.Views.ItemsPage">
    <StackLayout.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <util:IsZero x:Key="IsZero" /> 
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </StackLayout.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                <Label Text="Hello World" Grid.Row="{Binding UserL , Converter={StaticResource IsZero}}" Grid.Column="0" />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: The issue was that I had `x:Name` in my converter declaration, rather than `x:Key`. ‍♂️ Typical!

Comment: @Luke should have at least accepted my answer , give credit where credit is due

Comment: I don’t really feel like you gave me the solution, although you did spur me to look more closely at my code, so I’ll accept your answer on that basis.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Dumb mistake. Typical.

I was missing the `<ResourceDictionary>` tags, and also had `x:Name` instead of `x:Key` in the converter definition.